# What is this syntax called Bool bool = object.method() > 0 in Java

Tags: java, conditional-statements, boolean

I've just seen this line of code in my housemates code.

```
Bool bool = method() > 0;
```

or

```
string name = "Tony";
boolean nameIsTony = name == "Tony";
```

This would result in `nameIsTony` becoming `true`.

So you can have an inline conditional statement?

What is this called?

Comment: By the way: `Bool` is not a standard type in Java. You probably meant `boolean`.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I knew it wasn't correct for java, just wanted to get the point across quickly. I see that this is actually the same as doing many other types of combined expressions, it just looked like it was doing something more clever than it actually was!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`name == "Tony"` (or rather `name.equals("Tony")` as it should be) is a Boolean expression, so I'm guessing a Boolean expression is the closest term to what you are looking for.

It's an expression rather than a statement - it evaluates to something, rather than doing something. And it's not really conditional, as it always evaluates to a Boolean value - there's nothing conditional in its behaviour, just its result. So I'd go for "Boolean expression". The "inline" isn't really necessary.

Comment: And what would be a not inline boolean expression? I mean, I'd say that it's just an expression. If we look at the whole statement, then it's a variable declaration with initializer.

Answer (score 2):

its all about [Operator Precedence](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

equality(==) has higher precedence than assignment(=).

so `boolean nameIsTony = name == "Tony";`

1. first name == "Tony" expression evaluated as true
2. and than assigned to nameIsTony.

Comment: I know that here you are trying to answer how this expressions gets evaluated but it is also important to mention that this particular way of comparing two objects (or String object to a String literal as in this case) could be dangerous as that will compare the two for the address they are refering and not the values hold by the  address they are refering to. So better way to do that comparision is to do something like this: 
boolean nameIsTony = "Tony".equals(name);

Answer (score 1):

```
Bool bool = method() > 0;
```

assigns the result of the expression `method() > 0` - which is a `boolean` value - to the variable `bool`.

Certainly this can be a bit hard to read sometimes - I prefer to use brackets in such cases, like

```
Bool bool = (method() > 0);
```

I guess "inline logical expression" is an apt name for it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make such assignments more simple and clean, many languages including Java provides ternary operator (?:) which is used like this:

```
Employee emp = "manager".equals(profile) ? new Manager() : new Engineer();
```

So if profile equals "manager" then Employee emp is set to new Manager() else it is set to new Engineer().

Also note that I wrote "manager".equals(profile) instead of profile.equals("manager") reason being that even though both of them is correct but using 1st way is a better practice because in the 2nd way you will get a NPE (null pointer exception) if profile is null (unless and until you really want to report a NPE exception, in fact, even in that case beter way would be to add check for profile not equal to null).

Comment: I don't like this type of expression its too much verbose. e.g. `if(isAvailable == true ) doSomething();`.
i think `boolean b =  "Tony".equals(name); `
is fine.

Comment: @Vivart +1 for good catch!!!
What I really meant was for some scenario like this:
`Number obj = ((x % 2) == 0) ? new EvenNumber() : new OddNumber();`

Answer (score 0):

It's called "assignment".

Answer (score 0):

With few exceptions, expressions can be nested inside other expressions. Thus, each of these is boolean expression:

```
true
false
x > 0
(x >= 0) && (x <= 5)
100 == 100
Integer.parseInt("100") == 100
true & (true) & ((true)) & (((true)))
```

With regards to, say, local variable declaration, you can use *any* expression (as long as it's grammatically and semantically correct).

So there's really nothing special in something like:

```
boolean b = (x >= 0) && (x <= 5); // nothing special
```

In fact, you can also nest assignments like this:

```
x = y = z; // use judiciously!
```

---

#### Looking at the grammar

Consider the following excerpt from the Java Language Specification:

> [JLS 14.4 Local Variable Declaration Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/statements.html#14.4)
>
> A *local variable declaration* statement declares one or more local variable names.
>
> ```
> LocalVariableDeclarationStatement:
>         LocalVariableDeclaration ;
>
> LocalVariableDeclaration:
>         VariableModifiers Type VariableDeclarators
>         
> VariableDeclarators:
>         VariableDeclarator
>         VariableDeclarators , VariableDeclarator
>
> VariableDeclarator:
>         VariableDeclaratorId
>         VariableDeclaratorId = VariableInitializer
>
> VariableDeclaratorId:
>         Identifier
>         VariableDeclaratorId [ ]
>
> VariableInitializer:
>         Expression
>         ArrayInitializer
> ```

Here we see that a local variable declaration statement allows an optional initialization for each identifier. Each `VariableInitializer` is grammatically either an `Expression` or an `ArrayInitializer`.

Thus, a `someType anIdentifer = someExpression;` in this context is simply a local variable statement with an initializer. `someExpression` can grammatically be any expression.

---

#### Note on `ArrayInitializer`

`ArrayInitializer` are things like `{ 1, 2, 3 }` and `{ 4, 5, 6 }`. Note that the `ArrayInitializer` grammatical rule is not part of the `Expression` production. This is why you can do, say, `int[] x = { 1, 2, 3 };` in a declaration with initializer, but not later `x = { 4, 5, 6 };` in an assignment.